# Python constructing and formting char array to be written in CSV

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, char

I am new to python, and I need to write a row to csv file.

The format of row is: [[A][0][1][2].....[400]]

The values [1] to [400] is an image of size 20*20 in a numpy array, that I reshape into a row, and value A is an argument.

How do I construct a char array in python to achieve the above structure?
Also how can the same be deconstructed into a numpy int array and a char variable?

Sorry, might seem basic but I am struggling with this.

Comment: what is the value `[0]` ?

Comment: the value [0]? Any random number between 0 - 255.

Answer (score 0):

```
a= np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(20, 20))
print("[[A]{}]".format(np.array2string(a.ravel(), max_line_width=1e6, separator="][")))
```

Comment: Hey, While the same does form a string, How can the same be appended to a csv file? Can I transform the string back to array and the use numpy savetext() method?

Comment: to append the string to a csv file, you need to open the file in append mode, and write the string to csv.